# Apple Music - The code you entered is not valid

Tags: accounts, apple-music, android

My father created a family membership for apple music, and I created an apple account (icloud.com) for that purpose (I'm in the family group).

I'm trying to login from the Apple Music Android app, and keep getting `The code you entered is not valid. Try again.` in the account review part.

What should I do to set it up correctly? It's a new account, I've never used Apple services before and I also don't have any products except this membership. Should I login to an Apple device, download iTunes for my PC, or anything else? What am I missing?

**2018 Update:** After more than a year, I still haven't got a response from the customer support. It won't happen ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

An Apple Music Family Membership requires iCloud Family Sharing to be set up.

According to Apple:

> Family Sharing requires a personal Apple ID signed in to iCloud and iTunes. Music, movies, TV shows and books can be downloaded on up to 10 devices per account, five of which can be computers. iOS 8 or later and OS X Yosemite or later are required to set up or join a Family Sharing group, and are recommended for full functionality. Not all content is eligible for Family Sharing. Content can be hidden by family members; hidden content is not available for download. Content downloaded from family members or acquired via redemption codes is not subject to Ask to Buy.
>
> iCloud requires iOS 5 or later on iPhone 3Gs or later, iPod touch (3rd
>   generation or later), iPad Pro, iPad Air or later, iPad or later, or
>   iPad mini or later; a Mac computer with OS X Lion 10.7.5 or later; or
>   a PC with Windows 7 or Windows 8 (Outlook 2007 or later or an
>   up-to-date browser is required for accessing email, contacts and
>   calendars). Some features require iOS 10 and macOS Sierra. Some
>   features require a Wi-Fi connection. Some features are not available
>   in all countries. Access to some services is limited to 10 devices.

Since you're saying you're already in the family group, I expect the problem you're having is that you're using an Android device (the above seems to imply you need to be on macOS, iOS or Windows). I would do the following:

1. Contact Apple to check if there is a way around this conundrum and, if not,
2. Send [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/apple-music.html) to Apple as well as an email to support@apple.com (that's the email address they use for support re their Android apps).

I would think that since Apple offers the Apple Music Android app that this is an unintended consequence of how things are currently set up, so sending feedback is the only way of getting things changed.

Comment: Thanks for detailed your reply! I've just installed iTunes on windows and tried to connect with it, and also tried to login to an iPhone 5 device - but I'm still getting the message `The code you entered is not valid` from both iTunes on windows and iPhone 5. The message is received in the `Review Your Address` section in the login process

Comment: I'll try sending them an email, and post and update later

Comment: Just had a thought - are you and your dad by any chance in different countries? Or, more to the point, have iTunes accounts for different iTunes stores? If so that would explain the issue - a family group has to belong to the same iTunes Store (i.e. country). If not, it'll be interesting to see what response you get. It may also be worth contacting Apple Support by phone - you'll probably get a faster resolution that way.

Comment: Interesting, although we are in the same country, but I have no idea how to account is set. I've sent them an email, lets see what they say about it!

Comment: I tried to create an apple id with my gmail account, and now everything works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Wow, that is interesting. Glad you got it working! :) As an aside, can you think of anything that happened differently when you created your gmail account Apple ID? And has Apple responded yet?

Comment: (Apple haven't responded yet). I think that this time I finished the review process before joining the family group - Created the account, logged in from iTunes on windows and only then joined the family sharing

Comment: Well, when you have the time it may be worth adding an _answer_ to that effect as it's most likely the solution to your problem and may help others. Although you could wait a while to see what Apple says when they respond, in case it's also worth adding to your answer.

Comment: I thought about waiting for their answer, and then sum it up as an answer here. Thanks for the help and interest!